# Laravel error Primary Key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, mariadb

Buenas, estoy introduciendome un poco en Laravel y estoy pasando un codigo que tengo en pdo, estoy con la creación de tablas y me indica este error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near'
num_documento(`titulo_documento`
)' at line 1 (SQL: alter table `documentos` add primary key
`acronimo_proye
cto` using num_documento(`titulo_documento`))

[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error 
in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB
server version for the right syntax to use near  num_documento(`titulo_documento`)' at line 1
```

Y este es mi código

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('documentos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->string('titulo_documento', 50);
        $table->char('acronimo_proyecto', 3);
        $table->string('estado', 10);
        $table->string('idioma', 10);
        $table->char('num_documento', 2);
        $table->char('version', 1);
        $table->char('revision', 1);
        $table->text('descripcion');
        $table->date('fecha');
        $table->char('confidencialidad', 1);
        $table->char('acronimo_documento', 4);
        $table->char('acronimo_subcategorias', 3);
        $table->char('acronimo_usuario', 4);
        $table->char('aprobado', 4);
        $table->char('autorizado', 4);
        $table->char('revisor', 4);
        $table->char('acronimo_empresa', 3);
        $table->string('codigo_proyecto', 30);

        $table->primary('titulo_documento','acronimo_proyecto','num_documento','version','revision','codigo_proyecto');
        $table->foreign('acronimo_subcategorias','acronimo_proyecto')->references('acronimo_subcategorias','acronimo_proyecto')->on('tipo_de_documentos')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('acronimo_usuario')->references('acronimo_usuario')->on('usuarios')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('aprobado')->references('acronimo_usuario')->on('usuarios')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('autorizado')->references('acronimo_usuario')->on('usuarios')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('revisor')->references('acronimo_usuario')->on('usuarios')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('acronimo_empresa')->references('acronimo')->on('companias')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('acronimo_proyecto')->references('acronimo_proyecto')->on('proyectos')->onDelete('cascade');

    });
}
```

En las foreign no creo tener ningún error, pero hasta no resolver el de las PK no podre seguir revisando las FK, pero aun asi el error viene de la construccion de la primary.
Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es tener una llave primaria compuesta, debes pasar un array:

```
$table->primary(['titulo_documento', 'acronimo_proyecto', 'num_documento', 'version', 'revision', 'codigo_proyecto']);
```

Más información en la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#creating-indexes

Comment: Que raro, tengo esta otra compuesta `$table->primary('acronimo_documento','acronimo_subcategorias');` y funciona asi, si la meto en un array con corchetes no funciona

Comment: El segundo parámetro que acepta el método `primary()` es el nombre que llevará la llave, por lo cual asumo que no es lo que deseas, mira su código: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L346

Comment: no entiendo bien dicha documentación pero voy a ver, pero si el problema es la PK, si la dejo en solo dos campos funciona, pero si le añado más deja de funcionar, ahora debo de comprender como poner todas esas PK que necesito, por que tú codigo tambien me genera error., asi que el problema lo heredo desde esta compuesta `$table->primary('acronimo_documento','acronimo_subcategorias');`

Comment: Realmente y con todo respeto, te falta entender mucho más como funciona Laravel y las migraciones, no es que "funcione" así, si quieres mira en la base de datos los indices, verás que de esa sintaxis no resulta lo que deseas.

Comment: Mi recomendación sintiéndolo mucho es que si vas a trabajar con laravel no utilices llaves compuestas, laravel no tiene soporte para ellas por defecto. Pero si decides utilizarlas tendrás que hacer parches o utilizar otro ORM que no sea eloquent. Echa un vistazo ha esto https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5517

Answer (score 0):

Si no me equivoco tienes que pasar un array :

```
  $table->primary(['titulo_documento','acronimo_proyecto','num_documento','version','revision','codigo_proyecto']);
```

Como pone en la documentación , ya te señala que es **un string** o **un array** con las columnas deseadas.

> Fluent primary(string|array $columns, string $name = null) Specify the
>   primary key(s) for the table.
>
> Parameters string|array   $columns     string $name    Return Value Fluent

[Link : Api schema builder , blueprint](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_primary)